# OmniXML blank Nodes

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7

How will know if there is a blank node in xml...

The XML file have a structure like this:

```
<rollercoaster build="0.1 (Dec 30 2010)" debug="no">
    <settings name="roller coaster" sourcefile="rolcost.pas">
        <description>Roller Coaster admin function</description>
        <year>2010</year>
        <manufacturer>ArtTeck</manufacturer>
            <sears name="sears.uk" size="1024"  mda="87117ba5082cd7a615b4ec7c02dd819" region="england" set1="25d"/>
    <sears name="sears.dk" size="1056"  mda="326dbbf94c6fa2e96613dedb53702f8" region="denmark" set1="25d"/>
    <sears name="sears.gr" size="6802"  mda="01b4c38108d9dc4e48da4f8d5821377" region="greece" set1="65d"/>
    </settings>
    <settings name="roller coaster2" sourcefile="rolcost2.pas">
        <description>Roller Coaster user function</description>
        <year></year>
        <manufacturer>ArtTeck</manufacturer>
    </settings>...... and goes on
</rollercoaster>
```

The things I want to know are:

Example the second year is empty and when i try to get text node i get an error and stops the produser how can i pass this error or better how can i control the blank node ...
Thank you....

here is the code

```
for iNode := 0 to rollerList.Length - 1 do
begin
  Conf.nxtgrd.BeginUpdate;
  noderoller := rollerList.Item[iNode];
  Conf.nxtgrd.Cell[0,RowNum].AsBoolean := StrToBool(GetNodeTextStr(noderoller,'description'));
  if GetNodeTextStr(noderoller,'year') <> '' then // here get the exception...
                Conf.nxtgrd.Cell[1,RowNum].AsString := GetNodeTextStr(noderoller,'year');
  Conf.nxtgrd.EndUpdate;
 end;
```

Simply storage isn't for delphi 7?
p.s. I correct the above xml example in second year...

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to get text of some XML node and you get an exception. First post the code with which you try to get the text. And point to the exact node in your example that is empty.

I would suggest using SimpleStorage but I see you are still on Delphi 7. At least make sure you use OmniXMLUtils.

Comment: Besides that, the second year node is NOT empty in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if GetNodeTextStr(nodegame,'year') <> '' then
```

just use the overloaded version

```
if GetNodeTextStr(nodegame,'year', '') <> '' then
```

This one takes default value and returns that if the text node is not found. I also see a problem here. You iterate through a list of nodes, but where do you get "nodegame" from. Are you sure that this node is not nil? I think it should be like this:

```
if GetNodeTextStr(noderoller,'year', '') <> '' then
```

Unfortunately SimpleStorage is BDS 2006 and up compatible.

Comment: Thank you runner you help a lot... i just dont see the overladed function foolish man...

Comment: GetNodeTextStr is "smart" and returns empty string if first parameter is nil or if subnode doesn't exist.

Comment: It would have been slightly more idiomatic to have had a TryGetNoteTextStr or GetNodeTextStrDef, but other than small nits like this that I like to pick on, OmniXML is just gorgeous.  I love OmniXML. Everybody should use it!

Comment: @Warren: Have you looked at SimpleStorage? ;) The one for OmniXML not the Amazon :)